# Absolutely continuous function on R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-integral

What is the definition of absolute continuity in whole  $\mathbb{R}$.
I know the definition on an interval $[a, b]$. I have a trouble with understanding the definition of absolute continuity in whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: what do you know about the absolute continuity on $[a,b]$ ? Suppose $f$ is $continuous$ on $[a,b]$ then can you say when $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @seeker f is continuous on R iff f is continuous on each [a,b]. The analog for absolute continuity is not the same.

Comment: I think it is a good question!

Answer (score 1):

Let I be any finite interval of $\mathbb{R}$. A function $f\colon I\to \mathbb {R}$ is absolutely continuous on I if for every positive number $\varepsilon$ , there is a positive number $\delta$ such that whenever a finite sequence of pairwise disjoint sub-intervals $(x_{k},x_{k+1})$ of I satisfies
    $$\sum _{k=1}^{n}\left(x_{k+1}-x_{k}\right)<\delta \mbox{  then}\displaystyle \sum _{k=1}^{n}|f(x_{k+1})-f(x_{k})|<\epsilon$$
in particular just take $I=[a_{n},b_{n}]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. 
Then you can think as restrictions $f_{n}:[a_{n},b_{n}]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, $ with $f_{n}(x)=f(x) $ if for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $f_{n}$ is absolutely continuous we say that $f$ is continuous.

In words it means that when you restrict $f$ to any finite interval $[a,b]$ 
the restriction $f_{[a,b]}$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Note that the sequence of subintervals is usually _not_ a partition of $\mathbb R$, as this would require $x_{n+1}=\infty$ (It is, however a partition of $(x_1,x_{n+1})$. The implication will still be true, but it will only be non-trivial if $x_{n+1}-x_1 < \delta$.

Comment: Yes @Roland, but I do not understand perfectly you point of view can you explain a little better? Thank you!

Comment: I just think that the term 'partition' is giving a false impression, at least if you're not specifying what it partitions - we're not interested in partitions of the domain of $f$ (i.e. $[a,b]$ or $\mathbb R$), but for partitions of (small) subintervals $(x_1,x_{n+1})$ of the domain. I just thought that the 'in words' part was a bit misleading, and it would be important to emphasise that the definition of absolute continuouity is a local property, which is easily extended to 'locally on every subinterval of $\mathbb R$'.